# How to focus on Entry Control

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating a Xamarin.Forms app in a PCL.

In my app, the user has the option to use ZXing barcode reader or use Bluetooth barcode reader.

When the user selects the Bluetooth barcode reader, I replace the ZXing barcode reader to Entry Control.

When the user scans anything from Bluetooth barcode scanner I want to place that barcode in the textbox. My issue is that I want to set the focus of the Entry control, so when the user scans anything that will appear at entry control.

**XAML**

```xml
<StackLayout x:Name="layoutouterFrame" BackgroundColor="Green">
    <Frame Padding = "5" BackgroundColor="#ffffff">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid x:Name="grid">

            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

My code for Focus.

```cs
if (Constants.Scanner == "Zxing")
{
    /* My code for zxing control */
}
else
{
    Entry txtentry = new Entry { WidthRequest = 200 };
    txtentry.Focus();
    grid.Children.Add(txtentry);
}
```

Thanks for your comments and view.

Comment: You should focus the control after it is rendered on screen. It can change on each device but I guess 300ms is enough. So, try to wait for 300ms after you add the `txtentry` to `grid` then call `Focus` (i.e.: `Task.Delay(300).Wait(); txtentry.Focus()`)

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza sorry but this not workes

Comment: Did you tried a bit more time on wait (600ms for example)? Have you changed the order of `Children.Add()` and `Focus()`?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza The control change are happening on page 1 where user select the scanner type. And after that on page two we check the user choice then we add the control according to that.